# Unable to parse XML using java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an XML string got as a response. But I am unable to reach at Response Code and remarks. Can anybody help me to get the response code.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetIMEIInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetIMEIInfoResult>
        <![CDATA[
        <SerialsDetail>
          <Item>
            <ResponseCode>2</ResponseCode>
            <Remark>Invalid Input</Remark>
          </Item>
        </SerialsDetail>
        ]]>
      </GetIMEIInfoResult>
    </GetIMEIInfoResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thats how I am trying to do

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Remark");
        System.out.println(list.getLength());
        Node n = list.item(0);
        System.out.println(n.getTextContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean "unable to reach" ? what did you try?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code.

Comment: Please suggest. I have added the code. @GeorgHenkel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for an element with name "Remark", but you document does not contain such an element. Instead, it contains only an "GetIMEIInfoResult" element with a bunch of text in it. This text happens to be xml. But in order to access the contents of the inner piece of XML, you have to parse the contents of the "GetIMEIInfoResult" in the same way that you've parsed the entire document.

Here is how you can do it:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class NestedCDATA {

    private static String response = 
        "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "  <s:Body>" +
        "    <GetIMEIInfoResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
        "      <GetIMEIInfoResult>" +
        "        <![CDATA[" +
        "        <SerialsDetail>" +
        "          <Item>" +
        "            <ResponseCode>2</ResponseCode>" +
        "            <Remark>Aawwwwwwww yeaaaah!</Remark>" +
        "          </Item>" +
        "        </SerialsDetail>" +
        "        ]]>" +
        "      </GetIMEIInfoResult>" +
        "    </GetIMEIInfoResponse>" +
        "  </s:Body>" +
        "</s:Envelope>";

    public static String getCdata(Node parent) {
        NodeList cs = parent.getChildNodes();
        for(int i = 0; i < cs.getLength(); i++){
            Node c = cs.item(i);
            if(c instanceof CharacterData) {
                CharacterData cdata = (CharacterData)c;
                String content = cdata.getData().trim();
                if (content.length() > 0) {
                  return content;
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
            Node cdataParent = doc.getElementsByTagName("GetIMEIInfoResult").item(0);
            DocumentBuilder cdataBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document cdataDoc = cdataBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
              getCdata(cdataParent)
            )));
            Node remark = cdataDoc.getElementsByTagName("Remark").item(0);
            System.out.println("Content of Remark in CDATA: " + getCdata(remark));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result: "Content of Remark in CDATA: Aawwwwwwww yeaaaah!".

Here is another interesting question for you: why does your service output XML with XML in it? XML all by itself is already nested enough. Is it really necessary to wrap parts of it in CDATA?

Comment: Thanks... It worked. And answer to your question is that it is not my XML. I am consuming a third party API, they are responding in this format, so I have to anyways parse this only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the XML is that the data in the tag `GetIMEIInfoResult` is `CDATA`. This causes the builder not to recognize it as XML. To access the data in the tag `GetIMEIInfoResult` you can use the following:

```
Element infoResult = (Element) list.item(0);
String elementData = getCharacterDataOfNode(infoResult.getFirstChild());

public static String getCharacterDataOfNode(Node node) {
    String data = "";
    if (node instanceof CharacterData) {
        data = ((CharacterData) node).getData();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Then you have to parse that data again with a `DocumentBuilder` where you can access the tag `Remark`. To get the content you have again work with the `getCharacterDataOfNode()` method.